System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.'
I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0. I have an API which returns compressed data. Simplified version of my code looks like this:
[HttpPost("[action]", Name = "GetData")]
public IActionResult GetData(string request)
{
     string data = GetStaticXMLFileData();
     data = CompressString(data);

     return new ContentResult
     {
         Content = data,
         ContentType = "text/xml",
         StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
     };
}

private string CompressString(string text)
{
    string compressedString;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gZipStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(text);
            }

            byte[] compressedData = memoryStream.ToArray();

            compressedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(compressedData);
        }
    }

    return compressedString;
}

This API endpoint is working well and I have tested this from Swagger.
Now, I am trying to consume them in my client code as under:
private string GetDataAPIResponse()
{
    string httpResponse = string.Empty;

    var urlValue = string.Format("https://localhost:44314/api/CompressedData/GetData?compress=true&result_format=xml");
    var requestUri = new Uri(urlValue);

    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<data>Test</data>"); //Sample Data Request
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, byteContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Task<Stream> task = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                task.Wait();
                Stream responseStream = Constants.IsCompressed ?
                                        new GZipStream(task.Result, CompressionMode.Decompress) :
                                        task.Result;

                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (var readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                        httpResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd(); //Here, I got the Error.
                }
            }
        }

        return httpResponse;
    }
}

I am not able to get the decompressed response using this code.
On this line of code, I am getting an error:
httpResponse = readStream.ReadToEnd();

Error is:

System.IO.InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method

Stacktrace:

at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, Int32& bytesRead)
at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCore(Span`1 buffer)
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,  Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()

Can someone please suggest me a solution?

If you want to enable response compression, you can follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-9.0

It is completely wrong to encode compressed data in UTF-8, let alone set the ContentType to text/xml. I really can't understand.

System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(compressedData) This line is flat wrong, you cannot reliably convert compressed data to/from text. Return it as a byte array or stream instead.

@shinjo:
I just want to implement "compression" in my APIs.
May be my way of compression is incorrect. Can you please suggest that how should I compress the response from my API so that in "client" code I don't need to make any change and it will work. I have tried different ways for compression like Convert.ToBase64String() in my API but such compressed response is not getting decompressed in the client.
All above mentioned code samples are simplified versions of my actual code. We have a requirement that we cannot change client, but yes, we can make changes in APIs.

@Charlieface:
I have tried using Convert.ToBase64String() but it is not working. I cannot return anything else other than ContentResult from my API. Can you please suggest some way?

Both client and server code are completely wrong. You shouldn't be re-encoding a compressded file back into text. Just pass it as bytes or a stream
[HttpPost("[action]", Name = "GetData")]
public IActionResult GetData(string request)
{
     string data = GetStaticXMLFileData();
     var compressedStream = CompressString(data);
     return new FileStreamResult(compressedStream, "text/xml");
}

private Stream CompressString(string text)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(gZipStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(text);
    }

    memoryStream.Position = 0; // seek back to start
    return memoryStream;
}

And the client shouldn't use .GetResult or .Wait, only await.
static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(); // use static or DI client to prevent socket exhaustion

private async Task<string> GetDataAPIResponse()
{
    var urlValue = $"https://localhost:44314/api/CompressedData/GetData?compress=true&result_format=xml";
    using var content = new StringContent("<data>Test</data>", Encoding.UTF8);
    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlValue , content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var decompressed = Constants.IsCompressed ?
                               new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress) :
                               responseStream;

    using var reader = new StreamReader(decompressed, Encoding.UTF8);
    var httpResponse = await readStream.ReadToEndAsync();
    return httpResponse;
}


Having said that, you should probably just use the built-in Automatic Compression/Decompression instead.
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
});

[HttpPost("[action]", Name = "GetData")]
public IActionResult GetData(string request)
{
     string data = GetStaticXMLFileData();
     return new ContentResult
     {
         Content = data,
         ContentType = "text/xml",
         StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
     };
}

And the client is:
static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All,
});

private async Task<string> GetDataAPIResponse()
{
    var urlValue = $"https://localhost:44314/api/CompressedData/GetData?compress=true&result_format=xml";
    using var content = new StringContent("<data>Test</data>", Encoding.UTF8);
    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlValue , content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var httpResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return httpResponse;
}


Yes, this is working Charlie. I am newbie and this helped me a lot...!
Thanks for your quick help. :)
